# Multidimensional array visualizer for Visual Studio using autoexp.dat

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visualizer

I have been trying to create a visualizer for Visual studio in autoexp.dat file. Can someone give me a few pointers?

Here is a stripped down version of the class declaration:

```cpp
template<class T>
class MyClass {
    T **v; 
    int nRow;
    int nCol; 
}
```

So far I have the following, which gives me the the first element of each row (as expected), but don't know how to expand it, so that I can get the rest of the columns.

```
MyClass<*>{
  children
  (
      #array
      (
        expr: $e.v[$i],         
        size: $e.nRow
      )
  )       
}
```

I haven't been able to find much on how to format autoexp.dat file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered the rank, and base expressions [as described here](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=120). Got it working. Not a fancy list...but it works.

```
   MyClass<*>{
      children
       (
          #array
          (
            rank: 2,
            base: 0,
            expr: $e.v[($i % $e.nRow)][($i - $i % $e.nRow)/$e.nRow],
            size: ($r==1)*$e.nRow+($r==0)*$e.nCol
          )
       )
    }
```